# Connect BLE devices with Raspberry pi 3 B

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, bluez

I know this is not the first time this question was asked but after trying every thing I could during a week, I still have problems.
I'm trying to connect to my Raspberry pi to BLE devices. I can scan them but not connect to them.

The last explanation I have followed was this github issue: https://github.com/ukBaz/python-bluezero/issues/30

And here is all the commands I have done to try to update bluez and make this connection works.

```
###Install RASPBIAN JESSIE LITE 
2017-01-11-raspbian-jessie-lite.img

###Updates
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get upgrade

###Add libs
$ sudo apt-get install bluetooth  bluez-tools build-essential autoconf glib2.0 libglib2.0-dev libdbus-1-dev libudev-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev git

###Get bluez-5.43
$ wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.43.tar.xz

$ tar xf bluez-5.43.tar.xz

$ cd bluez-5.43

###Patch bluez
$ wget https://gist.github.com/pelwell/c8230c48ea24698527cd/archive/3b07a1eb296862da889609a84f8e10b299b7442d.zip

$ unzip 3b07a1eb296862da889609a84f8e10b299b7442d.zip

$ git apply  -v c8230c48ea24698527cd-3b07a1eb296862da889609a84f8e10b299b7442d/*

###Install bluez
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --enable-experimental --enable-maintainer-mode

$ make -j 4 && sudo make install

### Add to /etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf 
<!-- allow users of bluetooth group to communicate -->
<policy group="bluetooth">
  <allow send_destination="org.bluez"/>
</policy>

$ sudo usermod -G bluetooth -a $USER

$ sudo sed -i '/^ExecStart.*bluetoothd\s*$/ s/$/ --experimental/' /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service

$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload

$ sudo service bluetooth restart

$ service bluetooth status

$ sudo reboot

$ sudo hcitool lescan
       LE Scan ...
       XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (name)

$ gatttool -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -I
       [XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX][LE]> connect
       Attempting to connect to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
       Error: connect error: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)


$ gatttool -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -t random -I
       [XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX][LE]> connect
       Attempting to connect to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
       Error: connect error: Connection refused (111)
```

Thank you for your help

**Edit for Constantin Chabirand's answer**

```
$ systemctl status bluetooth
    ● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled)
       Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-01-17 21:17:07 UTC; 1min 51s ago
         Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
     Main PID: 587 (bluetoothd)
      Status: "Running"
       CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
               └─587 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd --experimental


$ bluetoothctl
    [NEW] Controller B8:27:EB:FD:93:2B raspberrypi [default]
    [bluetooth]# scan on
    Discovery started
    ....

    [bluetooth]# scan off
    [bluetooth]# connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
    Attempting to connect to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
    Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

**Edit 2**

After reinstalling with the simple solution:

```
$ bluetoothctl -v
    5.43

$ systemctl status bluetooth 
    ● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled)
       Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-01-18 15:46:53 UTC; 3min 37s ago
         Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
     Main PID: 586 (bluetoothd)
       Status: "Running"
       CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
               └─586 /usr/local/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd --experimental

$ sudo bluetoothctl
    [bluetooth]# connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
    Attempting to connect to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
    Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

Comment: Well at this point either your BLE Device does not allow the connection or bluez is not working on your rpi.

Did you try to connect to another device using bluetoothctl ? Did it work ? Does "info XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" returns the correct information about your device ?

Comment: I have tried with other devices and the connection failed every times. And "info XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"  gives me correct informations (At least nothing weird according me). I also tried with an other rpi and it's the same result :s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank's to Constantin Chabirand, I made it work. I needed a few more command lines to make it work and I needed to change the advertising frequency of my BLE device (I still need to do some tests on that).

Here is the exact commands I used to install bluez on my rpi3 and connect to BLE devices:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install -y libusb-dev libdbus-1-dev libglib2.0-dev libudev-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev

wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.43.tar.xz
tar xf bluez-5.43.tar.xz
cd bluez-5.43/

./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo reboot

# check version
bluetoothctl -v

sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service
        # Add --experimental to this lane 
        ExecStart=/usr/local/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd --experimental

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
sudo reboot

sudo usermod -G bluetooth -a pi
sudo reboot
```

That's it. Thank's again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What is the result of the bash command **systemctl status bluetooth** ?

Can you start **bluetoothctl** (just type it in your shell) ?

I also use a raspberry pi 3 to connect to BLE devices and I don't need a patch. Start a fresh install with bluez5.43 and post the results of the two commands I've written

---

**UPDATE**

For the installation I did it the simplest way I could. I followed the "The simplest way to compile this package is:" section in the INSTALL file which is :

```
 wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.43.tar.xz

 tar xf bluez-5.43.tar.xz

 cd bluez-5.43.tar.xz

./configure

 make 

 make install
```

Did you succesfully connect to your BLE device using something else ? Like a smartphone ? There are applications out there that can read gatt atrributes.

**UPDATE 2**

I did not remove a thing. Merely installed bluez5.43 on top of the rest. When I run 
**bluetoothctl -v** it returns : 5.43.

When I run **apt list --installed** is can see the following packages installed automatically :

```
bluez/stable,now 5.23-2+rpi2 armhf [installed,automatic]
bluez-firmware/stable,now 1.2-3+rpi1 all [installed,automatic]
bluez-obexd/stable,now 5.23-2+rpi2 armhf [installed,automatic]
bluez-tools/stable,now 0.2.0~20140808-3 armhf [installed]
```

As you can see I still have the old version installed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added the results you asked for. Every think seems to work well but not the connection. I'm gonna try an other installation without the patch. Do you have a link explaining the installation you did ?

Comment: Did you uninstall bluez before installing the new version ?

Comment: Yes, I have several devices and apps that connect together. I'm trying with your simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to install the bluez-5.43 to get around bugs in the default bluez-5.23 when using bluetoothctl from scripts.

You could probably install the binary version from stretch, but my experience is that you often run into other dependencies.

I had the same problem under Ubuntu-16.04 and used the deb-src package from Ubuntu-Zesty, to fix that. Since this is just a debian package I used this on the Raspberry pi too, worked fine when using a USB-bluetooth dongle.  To make this work on the RPI-3, which has its bluetooth controller attached via a serial line, you need to install the ../issue/30 patches too.

The advantage of doing it this way, is that once your Raspbian will contain a newer bluez version it will replace what we do here, and if you got more raspbian system you of course only need to install the generated .deb packages

This is what I did (handsfree):

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get install devscripts debhelper dh-autoreconf flex bison libdbus-glib-1-dev libglib2.0-dev  libcap-ng-dev libudev-dev l
ibreadline-dev libical-dev check dh-systemd libebook1.2-dev

wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/bluez_5.43.orig.tar.xz
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/bluez_5.43-0ubuntu1.debian.tar.xz
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/bluez_5.43-0ubuntu1.dsc

tar xf bluez_5.43.orig.tar.xz
cd bluez-5.43
tar xf ../bluez_5.43-0ubuntu1.debian.tar.xz
# install patches relevant for rpi-3 bluetooth
. /etc/os-release
if [ $ID = raspbian ]; then
    wget https://gist.github.com/pelwell/c8230c48ea24698527cd/archive/3b07a1eb296862da889609a84f8e10b299b7442d.zip
    cd debian/patches
    unzip ../../3b07a1eb296862da889609a84f8e10b299b7442d.zip
    for i in c8230c48ea24698527cd-3b07a1eb296862da889609a84f8e10b299b7442d/*;do
        mv $i .
        basename $i >> series
    done
    rmdir c8230c48ea24698527cd-3b07a1eb296862da889609a84f8e10b299b7442d
    cd ../..
fi
# end of Raspian related patches
debchange --local=~lorenzen 'Backport to Xenial'
debuild -b -j4
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

This would should work under other Debian derived systems too,
https://askubuntu.com/a/884062/655086

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem that connecting and playing BLE devices with Raspberry Pi 3 built-in Bluetooth. First of all, I learned how to play and control a tool of ***bluetoothctl*** in virtue of below webpage.

[https://mcuoneclipse.com/2016/12/19/tutorial-ble-pairing-the-raspberry-pi-3-model-b-with-hexiwear/][1]

In this tutorial, after successful connection with your BLE devices, you can work with an attribute that you want to play with.

For example, if you want to work with the attribute of Bluetooth UART TX or RX, you just need to input commands below, then read or write a value of that attribute of characteristic.

```
list-attributes 00:34:40:0A:00:4E 
select-attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_32_40_08_00_12/service0026/char0027
read 
write
```

If there is anyone who is fully aware of creating bluetooth connecting between Raspberry Pi 3 built-in BLE with Arduino Ble, Please share your knowledge. ;)